# Show a toast message when a text is recognized from camera

Tags: android-vision

I am trying to detect a text with a specific format from a live camera feed and show a toast message when that text is detected automatically.
I was able to detect the text and put a box around it. But I'm having a hard time showing that toast message.

This is the receiveDetections method from the Processor

```
@Override
public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
    mGraphicOverlay.clear();
    SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
        TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
        if (item != null && item.getValue() != null) {
            Log.d("OcrDetectorProcessor", "Text detected! " + item.getValue());

            // Check if it is the correct format
            if (item.getValue().matches("^\\d{3} \\d{3} \\d{4} \\d{4}")){
                OcrGraphic graphic = new OcrGraphic(mGraphicOverlay, item);
                mGraphicOverlay.add(graphic);

                // Show the toast message

            }
        }


    }
}
```

-> Showing a toast is not my end goal, If I'm able to fix that I'll fix the main problem.
-> I'm building on top of the code labs tutorial for the text vision api

Comment: You don't mention the issue you're having. If I'm not mistaking, receiveDetections is not called in UI thread, you just need to post a runnable (via runOnUIThread, or via a Handler) on the UI thread to display your toast.

Comment: @badoualy I was having this error when trying to show the toast  'Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()'.

Comment: Yes, you get this because receiveDetections is not called on the UI thread as mentioned in my first comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First pass context to `OcrDetectorProcessor` class from `OcrCaptureActivity` and `runUiThread` from that context. This piece of code show all text at once. If you want to show words one by one you need to split from `TextBlock` items.

```
Context context;

OcrDetectorProcessor(GraphicOverlay<OcrGraphic> ocrGraphicOverlay, Context context) {
    mGraphicOverlay = ocrGraphicOverlay;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
    mGraphicOverlay.clear();
    final String result;
    String detectedText = "";
    SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {

        final TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
        OcrGraphic graphic = new OcrGraphic(mGraphicOverlay, item);
        mGraphicOverlay.add(graphic);
        detectedText += item.getValue();
    }
    result = detectedText;
    ((OcrCaptureActivity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```